# Typescript null in union type not working

Tags: javascript, typescript

```js
interface Address {
  a: string
}

interface End {
  state: {
    addrList: null | (Address[]);
  };
}

class End {
  state = {
    addrList: [{
      a: '1'
    }],
  };
}
```

```
Error: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type. 
Property 'state' must be of type '{ addrList: Address[] | null; }', but here has type '{ addrList: { a: string; }[]; }'.
```

Then I got this.

So, Am I missing something?

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIBN1QgZx8gbwChlk4AuZHMKUAcyIF8ijRJZEUBREdQkqmDiRKxUqTiYoAGWDVKIAK4AbZcgA+yABQYsuHAG0AugEoA3AMYXmRBMrh5kPPmMHCUAXn7iyU2fOQDVx8KZAByAEYwgVJGIwAaS2sgA

Online demo

Comment: Your example works perfectly fine for me, what TypeScript version are you on?

Comment: @Zer0 maybe you aren't using strict mode, try running `tsc --init`

Comment: What are you exactly trying to achieve which this code? You are creating a class and an interface with the same name, so typescript try to overlap them, but cannot because of type mismatch.

Comment: Are you trying to do [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIBN1QgZx8gbwChlTk4AuZHMKUAcyIF8iiEAbOPZAURHUIkyNOJCoFymKABlgNKiACu7dsgA+yABQYsuHAG0AugEoA3MibIAvILJ3JWWfOT7i99+SoByAIxeh7kyGADQBFqbMREA)?  You are using [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#introduction) in your code but you probably shouldn't be.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIBN1QgZx8gbwChlk4AuZHMKUAcyIF8ijRJZEUBREdQkqmDiRKxUqTiYoAGWDVKIAK4AbZcgA+yABQYsuHAG0AugEoA3AMYXmRBMrh5kPPmMHCUAXn7iyU2fOQDVx8KZAByAEYwgVJGIwAaS2sgA

Comment: Thank you guys.  I want add type to class just it

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to implement interface that's why your End class doesn't know what should be assigned to **addrList**. Also interface should have I before the name (it's just the pattern), so that you will avoid the name clash.

Check this out

```js
interface IAddress {
  a: string
}

interface IEnd {
  state: {
    addrList: (IAddress[] | null);
  };
}

class End implements IEnd {
  state = {
    addrList: [{
      a: '1'
    }],
  };
}
```